# Getting info with same data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I can't really put it into words cause I'm not really good at english so I'll just give an example. And for that reason I can't really search how to do it. Hope you understand.

E.g: Say I have a table setup like this.

```
+-------------+---------+---------+----------+
| Category_ID | User_ID |  Info1  |  Info2   |
+-------------+---------+---------+----------+
|           1 |       1 | 'Info1' | 'Info2'  |
|           1 |       2 | 'Info3' | 'Info4'  |
|           1 |       3 | 'Info5' | 'Info6'  |
|           1 |       4 | 'Info7' | 'Info8'  |
|           1 |       5 | 'Info9' | 'Info10' |
+-------------+---------+---------+----------+
```

Something like that. So what I want is to get every user that is using/in category_id of 1. And then print out the information they have. Is that even possible? Just explain to me how to do it I already have a method for getting info in and out of mysql.

<kbd>Note #1: The idea is to print out a div template for each of the user so it will be like a list kinda thing.</kbd>
To be honest the only thing I have tried was <kbd>'SELECT * FROM table WHERE Category_ID =1 GROUP BY column_choice'</kbd>. 

Hopefully you guys understood what I said. Sorry I'm not really good at english.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Category_ID =1 GROUP BY column_choice` - Read up on SELECT https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: So are you wanting to get data from this table, or the user's data from you user table?

Comment: Does the following make sense to you? `SELECT * FROM table WHERE category_ID = 1;` I'd recommend you take a look at  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/ or some other SQL tutorial!

Comment: You are supposed to read the rules, so I'll assume you did. Anyway, I want to know (just like rules say you have to explain)... **what have you tried?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three ways to do it.

First: Use cartesian product of your tables and filter it out:

```
SELECT t.User_ID, u.ID, u.username, u.email FROM table AS t, users AS u WHERE t.Category_ID = 1 AND t.User_ID = u.ID;
```

Second: Join two tables together and get your results:

```
SELECT t.User_ID, u.username, u.email FROM table AS t NATURAL JOIN users AS where t.Category_ID = 1;
```

Third: Use a nested query to get user ids in category #1 then query users table and filter it by the set in previous part.

```
SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE ID in (SELECT User_ID FROM table WHERE Category_ID=1;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch them all and put them in a div. You can try this:

```
if($stmt = $YourConnection->prepare("SELECT Information FROM yourTable WHERE Category_ID = 1")){
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($information);
  while($stmt->fetch()){
    ?>
      <div>
        <?php echo $information; ?>
      </div>
    <?php
  } /* END OF WHILE LOOP */
  $stmt->close();
} /* END OF PREPARED STATEMENT */
```

I hope you know how to establish your connection and just replace the necessary *table name* and *connection variable* above.

Comment: Stack's syntax highlighting's telling me there's a syntax error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Noticed it too. Sorry for that. Fixed!

Comment: No worries, thought I'd let you know ;-)

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper - You mean fetching of **all** information? Yes. That is what my code does for you. Fetch all row/information that has the `Category_ID` of `1`

Comment: @LoganWayne Well okay I'll try this.

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper - you just have to replace the `connection variable`, `column name` and `table name` (if necessary).

Comment: @LoganWayne How would I go about using this in a PDO? I just google'd it and apparently the `bind_result` method does not work in PDO. Would `bindValue()` be any good you think?

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL command:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Category_ID=1;
```

Comment: that's been established in comments. they also want to print it out too.  *And then print out the information they have.*

Comment: @Fred-ii-, ahh, didn't see that.  Why *do* people write answers as comments instead of answers?

Comment: How would I do this for multiple stuff? Like get the first user who has it then get there data print it out and do it for the next one who has this category_id? (Does that make any sense?)

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper, yes your question makes sense, but generally when querying MySQL people tend to get all the responses (rows) at once and then use PHP (or whatever the server language is) to cycle through them.  You'll have to get more detailed about the environment you're in for help with that.

Comment: @user1717828 we're just strange like that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Information FROM table_name WHERE Category_ID = 1
```

Comment: yes, the sintax is SELECT column_name1, column_name2, column_name_n FROM table_name WHERE condition_looked, ---> see an SQL tutorial on http://www.w3schools.com/sql/